# How many observations over an atom can be made?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In order to determine the orbitals of any unknown atom , is it possible to make and record direct observations of electrons around the atom without disturbing the atom ? How many observations can one make without loosing the information about orbitals?
I guess direct observation of atom has been made.

Comment: Do you think electrons can be detected without disturbing them?

Comment: Electrons in quantum mechanics are non-localized. When observed directly the wave function collapses and are found somewhere according to its potential distribution.But does that mean atom ceases to exist as it was before the observation ?

Comment: *Every* measurement impacts the electron - or any physical system - in quantum mechanics. How long you may play - it depends what property of the electrons you measure. For example, if you measure the energy, you get one of the allowed energy eigenstates, and it's there again. Instead, if you decide to measure the exact location $\vec r$ of the electron, you may get it but the momentum $\vec p$ becomes infinitely uncertain after the measurement, by the uncertainty principle. This corresponds to almost 100% certainty that the momentum is large enough for the electron to escape the nucleus.

Comment: Your question is not very clear, you could make any number of observations without affecting the other _if_ they commute, for your question in the comment,  I believe that  not all physicists agree on a single answer, there are different interpretations for it, see Griffiths Chapter-1

Comment: So an exact measurement of the location unavoidably ionizes the atom. If you repeat the measurement of the location a moment later, the electron will be at a different place. You may also measure the momentum vector. You get some reasonable quantity agreeing with the expectation that the kinetic energy is comparable to the binding energy in the atom. After the measurement, the location becomes totally uncetain - in the whole space - so it's again almost certain that the atom got ionized. But there are also "limited accuracy" measurements, e.g. measure in which tenth of the atom the electron is

Comment: The purpose of my experiment was to know the orbitals of an unknown atom by making N observations. However it seems to be impossible because as soon as the measurement of location of electron is made , the atom ionizes. If there are N unknown atoms of same kind then the orbitals can be determined ,I guess, by making N observations, but in the process I will loose those hard earned atoms.

Comment: This video shows atoms combining to form one.                                                                      https://youtu.be/p9dn-Umr7VU                                                                                How is the observation not disturbing the electrons of the atom ?

Comment: Have a look http://io9.gizmodo.com/the-first-image-ever-of-a-hydrogen-atoms-orbital-struc-509684901 it has a link to the publication

Answer (score 0):

In 2011 scientists were capable for the first time to [directly measure](http://www.nature.com/nchem/journal/v3/n4/full/nchem.1008.html) the shape of an orbital. They used a modified scanning tunneling microscope. These are  able to probe the density of electrons in whatever it's scanning, although it typically doesn't have the resolution to see those electron orbitals in detail. The researchers improved the resolution by adding carbon monoxide on the scanning tip and insulating the substance being scanned with a layer of salt. In this way they were able were able to boost the sensitivity of the microscope, and scan electron orbitals for the first time